# Add inherited TextBox to ToolStrip

Tags: c#, textbox, toolstrip, inherited

It seems like it's not possible for some reason but it worth a try:
Is it possible to add inherited TextBox to a ToolStrip?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom textbox, you will need to have your textbox inherit from ToolStripTextBox instead of just TextBox.  Then you can add it from code or the designer.

[image: Custom Toolstrip textbox]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you said manually meaning I created a class as follow: class IdTextBox : ToolStripTextBox, and also created a constructor that has no parameters, rebuild the solution, but I still don't have my idTextBox in the toolstrip tools list. By the way, I tried to add an inherited control (instead of  a class) but in the inheritance picker I get the following warning: "No built assemblies contain components to inherit from. Build the current application, or click Browse and select a previously built assembly from another application".

Comment: Are they in the same project? Is the class public?